# Wordpress Install with other software installed in a subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm having an issue that I think can be solved with .htaccess, however, I'm not sure exactly how, htaccess rules have never been a strong point for me.

I have a domain with WHMCS installed on it, in a subdirectory, like this:

`/websites/manage/`

the `/websites/` directory is otherwise empty.

Now, I have installed WordPress on the root of the domain, and I want to use the /websites/ location in the WordPress permalink structure, as I want to build a WordPress page that describes the products and services available there, and use it as a gateway to the WHMCS portal located beneath it.

I've tried searching for an answer to this problem, but I keep turning up tons of results about installing *wordpress* in a subdirectory, and nothing else.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

I should have mentioned:

Currently, I get the WHMCS portal when I go to `/websites/manage/`, which is fine.

However, my problem is that when I go `/websites/` I get a directory listing instead of my WordPress page.

Comment: You can add a rule to bypass /websites/manage/ directory from WordPress. However, you will have to make sure not to use /websites/manage/ in your WordPress permalinks, since they won't work.

Comment: Actually, this isn't a problem.  Currently if I navigate to the /websites/manage/ dir I get the WHMCS portal.  My problem is that when I go to the /websites/ directory, I get a directory listing instead of my WordPress page.  I should have mentioned this above.

Comment: Then you don't have an index page set and/or directory indexing is on. `DirectoryIndex index.php` then `Options -Indexes`

Comment: @PanamaJack thanks, but I couldn't get this to work, so I ended up using a mod_rewrite rule to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding the following to the beginning .htaccess file, before the WordPress section:

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/websites/$
RewriteRule . /index.php
</IfModule>`

This redirects the /websites/ directory to the /index.php file which WordPress can then use to find its matching page.  It still allows the sub directory `/websites/manage/` to be controlled by the WHMCS software residing there.